# HTML2PDF with Nodemailer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, nodemailer, html2pdf

Trying to send a generated PDF from eKoopman's HTML2PDF.js to send as an email attachment-- but can't get the resulting PDF to display. Have tried a lot of the solutions on Stack Overflow and elsewhere, but many tend to be outdated.

HTML2PDF:

```
html2pdf().set(opt).from(iac).toPdf().output('datauristring')
    .then(function(pdf) {
        emailDoc(pdf)
    })
```

Attempts at the relevant parts of the mail options from emailDoc():

```
attachments: [{
   filename: 'Name.pdf',
   content: Buffer.from(pdf).toString('base64')
}]

attachments: [{
   filename: 'Name.pdf',
   content: Buffer.from(pdf).toString('base64'),
   contentType: 'application/pdf'
}]

attachments: [{
   filename: 'Name.pdf',
   content: new Buffer(pdf, 'base64'),
   contentType: 'application/pdf'
}]

attachments: [{
   filename: 'Name.pdf',
   content: pdf,
   encoding: 'base64'
}]
```

Doesn't necessarily have to be the base64 method, just any combination that will make this work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to save your pdf first, then upload it using path description like,

```
  attachments: [{
    filename: 'file.pdf',
    path: '/path/to/file',
    contentType: 'application/pdf'
  }],
```

Hope it helps!